# How can I replace this simple switch, with an automated alternative?

Tags: switches, solid-state-relay

I have a circuit that I'm changing that pulses current (maximum 1A) through an inductive load (a coil). A second coil is then used to detect the pulse transmitted from the first coil (a 2 coil metal detector). However, I need the option of just using one coil and connecting it directly to the second part of the circuit. Currently this is done with a simple switch **SW4**.

This is the transmit circuit with the coil connected across (6) and (5). SW4 is normally open but can be used to connect directly to the second part of the circuit, **if the user only wants to use a single coil configuration**.

[image]

This is the second part of the circuit where the second coil is connected across (4) and GND:

[image]

I want to automate this selection using a microcontroller rather than a manual SPST switch (full control of the system is through a touch screen except for this). Would a solid state relay be appropriate for this? It is likely that the user will only ever have the device in one configuration or the other. One thing to also consider is that the coils generate huge back EMF (over 250V+) that can't be removed as the operation of the device is reliant upon the back EMF. If an SSR would not be appropriate are there any alternatives to a manual slide switch?

Comment: Which switch? SW4? How would you connect the SSR? Note: If that's not your drawing or design then you need to credit it. (This is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).) Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes I'm effectively wanting to replace SW4. No, this design doesn't need to be credited.

Comment: "No, this design doesn't need to be credited." Are you saying that the drawing is your own? Even if an image is public domain, or released under a free license, site policy is to credit where an image was obtained.

Comment: The circuit is a small part of a much larger design developed by my company 30 years ago. it's not public domain, it's not designed by me but it also doesn't need to be credited. The posted parts of the circuit have no IP. I know what the site policy is, I find this a touch patronising...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a solid-state relay I would go for a mechanical relay. Two reasons:

1. They withstand well overvoltages between open contacts and towards the coil; values such as 1000 Vrms for 1 minute are commonplace.
2. They do not introduce capacitance, as the soild-state one would do, so you do not risk to compromise circuit operation (maybe resonance with the coils); it worked with SW4 switch, it will work with the relay, that has more or less the same capacitance.

It's a 2-way relay, just two contacts (you do not need really thee double-throw function, as per schematic).
There are many that can be driven with 5V, or if you can afford 12V. You can even choose a two-state relay, or (how it is commonly called) a latch relay.

Comment: Are there any particular characteristics that I would need to look for when choosing a relay? I'm hoping I can find a low-profile surface mount version.

Comment: @ChrisD91 Take your coil operating current and add some margin. Back EMF of several hundreds V should not be a problem; take insulation of 1500 Vrms 1 min just to be safe. Take note of the switched voltage level, so when the coils is connected, or think it is 240 Vrms and you are safe: the relay will be a bit larger. I use the OMRON G2RL: there is a 5V/80mA coil version (or 12V/33mA one), but they are not latched. Insulation levels: btw contacts same polarity = 1kVrms, btw contacts diff polarity=2.5kVrms, contacts-to-coil 5kVrms. This s example; there are others perfectly equivalent.